# When do I use nested fields in GraphQL and when do I flatten them?

Tags: graphql

With GraphQL schemas, when should I provide a type relation's field as a root-level field for its associated type?

## Example

In many examples, I almost always see schemas that require the client to create queries that explicitly traverse the graph to get a nested field.

For a **Rock Band Table**-like component in the front end (or client), the GraphQL service that provides that component's data may have a schema that looks like this:

```graphql
type Artist {
  name: String!
  instrument: String!
}

type RockBand {
  leadSinger: Artist,
  drummer: Artist,
  leadGuitar: Artist,
}

type Query {
  rockBand: RockBand
}
```

If the table component specified a column called, "**Lead Singer Name**", given the current schema, a possible query to fetch table data would look like this:

```graphql
{
  rockBand {
    leadSinger {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

For the same **Rock Band Table**, with the same column and needs, why not design a schema like this:

```graphql
type RockBand {
  leadSinger: Artist,
  leadSingerName: String,
  drummer: Artist,
  leadGuitar: Artist,
}
```

That way a possible query can be like this?

```graphql
{
  rockBand {
    leadSingerName
  }
}
```

---

Does the choice to include the "leader singer's name", and similar relation fields, entirely depend on the client's need? Is modifying the schema to serve data for this use-case too specific a schema? Are there benefits to flattening the fields outside of making it easier for the client? Are there benefits to forcing traversal through the relation to get at a specific field?

Comment: usually types=tables (`RockBands` and `Artists`) and separate resolvers (generated from db automaticaly) to each one/each query level (only Artist or only RockBand or both nested - that's why not flat) ... in you want to have one table, without relations (really ?), it can be flat ..... a lot of pros/cons about graphql, use google instead of SO

Comment: Thanks @xadm. If you'll allow me, I want to make sure I understand your comment:

For "usually types=tables" are you saying that a schema type is related to a datastore table, or the consumer/client's table component that requests the data from the GraphQL server?

If you have any recommended search terms for finding out more about when to provide relations/when to exclude in GraphQL queries or schemas, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: of course db tables / server/backend/api side  ... we're talking about data, structures, responses - not view (you can always flatten for rendering) ... you can freely model types and write resolvers manualy to manage data in db/files/whatever, even combine multiple tables into one type ... but you can model/test db and generate types, freely combine required data on demand (structured query is for that) ... usually much faster is to generate - depth is not a problem at all, even visual ... structure more readable